# Tensorflow: How do I load a SavedModel object and continue training?

Tags: tensorflow

I have saved the model with the following code:

```
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(save_dir)

tensor_info_input_image = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(input_image)
tensor_info_logits = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(logits)

prediction_signature = (
  tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
      inputs={'net_input': tensor_info_input_image},
      outputs={'logits': tensor_info_logits},
      method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME))

builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
  sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
  signature_def_map={
      tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
          prediction_signature 
  },
  )
builder.save()
```

I thought I could just load it by running the following code:

```
meta_graph_def = tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess,
                                [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
                                model_path)
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
net_input = graph.get_tensor_by_name(args.load_net_input_name)
net_output = graph.get_tensor_by_name(args.load_net_output_name)
network = graph.get_tensor_by_name(args.load_logits_name)
loss = graph.get_tensor_by_name(args.load_loss_name)
opt = graph.get_operation_by_name(args.load_optimizer_name)
```

However, when I run it, the value of `loss` appeared to revert back to the untrained model's. My expectation was to be able to continue where I left off. Also, is it possible to divide the training into two sessions?

- First session: Train with original data. Save the model.
- Second session: Load the model. Train with augmented data.

Thank you.